# Change image with link

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have a simple drop down with two links "before" and "after":

```
<img id="beforeAfter1" src="images/b2.jpg" width="580" height="435"/>
<div class="baDiv">
    <select class="baSelect" onchange="document.getElementById('beforeAfter1').src = this.value">
        <option value="images/b2.jpg">Before</option>
        <option value="images/a2.jpg">After</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When I click on one of these links the main image src changes. I want to convert these drop downs to plain links `Before | After` But I am not quite sure how to do that.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('beforeAfter1').src = 'images/b2.jpg';">Before</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('beforeAfter1').src = 'images/a2,jpg';">After</a>
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, such that:

```
<img id="beforeAfter1" src="images/b2.jpg" width="580" height="435"/>
<a id='before' value="images/b2.jpg">Before</a> |
<a id='after' value="images/a2.jpg">After</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#before').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#beforeAfter1').attr('src', 'images/b2.jpg');
  });
  $('#after').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#beforeAfter1').attr('src', 'images/a2.jpg');
  });
});
</script>
```